# Remove last entry from JavaScript history

Tags: javascript, html5-history

I have a requirement where i have to remove the last entry (state) from the history of JavaScript.
My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        history.replaceState(null, null, null);
        });
```

But this does not remove the last entry from JavaScript history and when i click back button i am re-directed the the latest entry in the history, which does show that latest entry is not replace/removed from the history object.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Instead, you can prevent the back button

Comment: I need to have back button but prevent the entry in history object, its the requirement @Hkachhia